# How to format in NSDate depending on the time difference?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I want to display a date in the following way:

- If it is today, then display the time only.
- If it is in the past week, then display "Yesterday", "Sunday", "Monday" etc.
- If it is more than one week ago, then display the actual date.

I am trying something to get something similar to how the date is displayed in the iPhone SMS application.

Comment: Have you tried to implement something? Sound pretty easy. Compare Date with Today. If it's today use Today, if it's less than one week ago use weekday, otherwise use exact date.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Thaks for your reply.I haven't tried it out.As I am new in iPhone development

Comment: Google before posting Question. You should have found answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why no use the method of

```
setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:
```

with it set to YES.  Now the formatter now will return 'today' or 'yesterday' or 'tomorrow' depending on the date that should be formatted.  If a relative format can't be found, then use the formatter will be used for the format.

Answer (score 1):

For more format patterns as below:

- Formatters in OS X v10.8 and iOS 6.0 use version [tr35-25](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
- Formatters in iOS 5.0-5.1 use version [tr35-19](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
- Formatters in OS X v10.7 and iOS 4.3 use version [tr35-17](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-17.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
- Formatters in iOS 4.0-4.2 use version [tr35-15](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-15.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
- Formatters in iOS 3.2 use version [tr35-12](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-12.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
- Formatters in OS X v10.6 and iOS 3.0-3.1 use version [tr35-10](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Answer (score 0):

Go through `NSDateFormatter`([link here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) and `NSDate` ([link here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) class documentation before asking a thing you have not even tried.

The `NSDateFormatter` class can be used to properly format the date into your choice with fixed parameters for different components of the date. For showing the full name of the day, use 'cccc' in the format. For eg

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setFormat:@"cccc dd-MM, HH:mm:ss"];
```

To compare dates, there are in built methods for comparing `NSDate` objects for eg `isEqualToDate` , `laterDate:` , `timeIntervalSinceNow` etc. Go through the Apple documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/isEqualToDate%3a)

Comment: Since `cccc` is used for the stand-alone week day I would recommend to use `EEEE` instead. The stand-alone versions should really only be used if they are used alone (e.g. in a calendar header). In russian, finnish or italian locale there is a difference between those two.